# Hardware Mediaplayer display

Tags: media-player

I'm looking for a keyboard or just a little display to attach on my keyboard or something like that, what will show me the music tracks i'm playing in windowsmedia player, itunes, etc.

I did some research and the only thing I found are gaming keyboards, but i'm not shure if these show my music tracks.

So my question:
Does somebody knows a keyboard who show the music tracks or just a little display?

Bye,

Eric

Comment: Are you asking for a display that is either built into the keyboard or is just an external device, which only works when a certain program is running and sole purpose to display song details.

Comment: I hope a external device because i have a realy nice keyboard allready. I work with audio for TV and when i'm looking for a nice sound effect while i'm in my audio software i want to see the track name instead of looking to the windowsmediaplayer window.

Comment: OK - I doubt it exists - it may be cheaper to get a second monitor.

Comment: I allready got an extra monitor. But is there a keyboard with a build-in lcd screen that give you the info of the windowsmediaplayer. Or do i have to search for the gaming keyboards?

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like an [Optimus mini three](http://www.artlebedev.com/everything/optimus/mini-three/overview/)